# Strange issue on ImageView with OnTouchListener while running Jelly Bean

Tags: android, imageview, ontouchlistener

I'm creating an ImageView programmatically on my interface, in this way:

```
...
ImageView image = new ImageView(getActivity());
TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(width, height);
image.setLayoutParams(params);
image.setPadding(5, 3, 5, 3);
image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
image.setTag(key);
image.setOnClickListener(this);
image.setOnTouchListener(this);
...
```

And this is my onTouch method:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // Apply the pressed effect on a button
    ImageView button = (ImageView) v;
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        button.setColorFilter(Color.argb(150, 155, 155, 155));
        return false;
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        button.setColorFilter(Color.argb(0, 155, 155, 155));
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Of course i implement OnTouchListener, and my goal is to add an effect to ImageView when it is pressed. But i noticed a strange behavior:

- if device/emulator has Jelly Bean, the ImageView disappears and never become visible after i clicked it;
- otherwise, if device/emulator has pre Jelly Bean version of Android (ICS, Gingerbread), the ImageView is ok and won't disappears from my interface.

Logcat does not report an error and i don't want/need to use ImageButton instead.

My questions are: am i missing something on my code? Why this is happening on two different version (but not so far) of Android release?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
I forgot to say that this code is part of a Fragment.

Comment: Could you try to `return super.onTouch(event);` at the end of the function instead of returning false each time ?

Comment: @ZouZou i forgot to say that this part of code is on a Fragment: when i added your line at my code, Eclipse say that the method "is undefined for the type Fragment"; so i changed it with     return super.getActivity().onTouchEvent(event);     and nothing has changed.

Comment: Did you remove all the `return false;` in the if/else block ?

Comment: @ZouZou yes, but now the ImageView is not disappearing (that's ok!) nor having the desired effect when i touch it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i don't have time to "Gandalfing" all sites and documentations and i end up with another solution.
I just added an animation on my ImageView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<alpha
    android:duration="100"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.5" >
</alpha>

<scale
    android:duration="10"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="0.9"
    android:toYScale="0.9" >
</scale>
</set>
```

Then i activate it on ImageView with onTouch event (activity or fragment must implements OnTouchListner):

```
image.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

Finally this is the onTouch method:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // Apply the pressed effect on a button
    ImageView button = (ImageView) v;
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        button.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.image_click));
        return false;
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in the Color value you are assigning to the ImageView.

```
Color.argb(0, 155, 155, 155)
```

0 for the alpha channel (which is the first parameter) means transparent. Check out the reference for more details: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html

Comment: I tried to change the Color, but nothing happen. Thanks for your answer.